# window.onload function not running

Tags: javascript, onload

I'm facing a weird issue. The console.log() outside the onload function works, but the console.log() inside doesn't work... Would it mean that my page never fully loads ? I had a look at the developer tools of Chrome and it shows me that the page is loaded, so I don't really understand... ([here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00Vlr.png) is a screen of the devtool)

Here is my code:

```
console.log("hello1");

window.onload = function()
{
    console.log("hello2");
};
```

(I'm using this in a WordPress website, but I don't think it changes anything)

Thanks in advance,

ArbreMojo.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7opyw5h4/ - it works fine by itself. Possibly something else has overridden the handler. If you're using something like WordPress there might be all kinds of scripts being loaded by the framework.

Comment: One other possibility is that this code is actually inside of another piece of code that runs after the `load` event fires. (As one example, if this were inside of a `click` event handler, and you did the click long after the page loaded.)

Comment: Thank you for your answers guys :) I don't think this code is inside of another piece of code, but it's possible that some other scripts of WordPress override the handler, as ADyson said it. I will continue to search :) Thanks a lot again !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some other code is probably assigning another function value to the `window.onload` method, so it basically overrides your assignment.

Instead of `window.onload = function` you can do:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  console.log('loaded')
})
```

which allows attaching an *arbitrary* number of handlers for that event. This ensures nothing can override your callback function.

See: [EventTarget.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) for more info.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Nicholas, however it still doesn't work... :/

Comment: You're probably attaching the listener after the document `load` event has fired. Replace `document` with `window`, which is more surefire for your case anyway. I'll amend. If it's still not working, see @apsillers comment on your OP.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nicholas, it works by replacing document by window ! :D